# Is there a limit argument size for the mysql prepared statements?

Tags: mysql, ruby, rubygems

OK, I've been stuck on this for some times now. I want to use the mysql gem to populate a database with data from an xml file but when I'm trying to execute prepared statements I have an issue.

```
@dbi = Mysql.new(@host,@userid,@pwrd,@database)

query = "INSERT IGNORE INTO sha1( sha1_date, sha1) VALUES (? , ?) "
@prep = @dbi.prepare(query)
res = @prep.execute( ir.date, ir.sha1)
#this first query works, i can find the inserted row in the DB

@prep = @dbi.prepare("SELECT id FROM sha1 WHERE sha1 = ?")
res = @prep.execute(ir.sha1)
puts res.fetch
#but here the prepared statement return an empty string.
```

I want to be able to do a SELECT like this because the final query would look something like that

```
    query = "INSERT INTO integration_job(sha1_id, branch_id, integration_stage_id, status_id, name) VALUES (
  (SELECT id FROM sha1 WHERE sha1 = ?),
    (SELECT id FROM branch WHERE name = ?),
    (SELECT id FROM integration_stage WHERE name = ?),
    (SELECT id FROM integration_status WHERE name = ?),
    ?)"
@prep = @dbi.prepare(query)
res = @prep.execute(ir.sha1, ir.branch, ir.stage, ir.status, ir.job
```

I've tried to do the same types of queries with other Tables and it worked. My guess is that the argument that I pass to the execute() method is too long.

```
puts ir.sha1 # => dba759e168e734fcc2eaf114269879177ef6a0b1
```

But i can't find informations about a limit size for the arguments so i don't realy know what to do.

So i have several questions :

- Is there a limit size for the execute() method arguments ? (and if so, what is it ?)
- How can i workaround this and do prepared statements with the same outcome but without the sha1 as an argument ? *Using an other gem is an idea but i don't know which one*.

**[Edit]** 
OK I found the solution, it's was simply that I limited the size of the VARCHAR field storing the sha1 to 40 characters. (It made sens to me has a sha1 IS 40 character long) But the parsing of the sha1 added a end-line character to the string , making it 41 char long. I removed it with gsub("\n") and everything works fine now.

Thanks for the comments, they made think about it differently.

Comment: It doesn't look like you're inserting a lot of data here. What sort of limit are you concerned about? Normally you can insert as much as MySQL's [`max_allowed_packet`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/program-variables.html) which can be adjusted as necessary but is usually enough.

Comment: What is the table definition for the table to which you inserting?